# Have difficulty in fetching data from sqlite in android while using datepicker

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
        {

// when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
    year = selectedYear;
    month = selectedMonth;
    day = selectedDay;              
    try
     {
db=openOrCreateDatabase("Lecturer",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
db.execSQL("Create Table If Not Exists temp (Month INTEGER,Date INTEGER,Year INTEGER,Event TEXT)");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO temp(Month, Date, Year, Event) VALUES (11,17,2012,'first')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO temp(Month, Date, Year, Event) VALUES (10,9,2012,'second')");
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM temp",null);
c.moveToFirst();
while(c.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
     t2=c.getString(0);
    // Log.e("",""+t2);
     int n = Integer.parseInt(t2);
     t3=c.getString(1);
     int n1 = Integer.parseInt(t3);
     t4=c.getString(2);
     int n2 = Integer.parseInt(t4);
     t5=c.getString(3);
     EditText t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     Log.e("",""+day);
     if(day==n&& month==n1&&year==n2)
        {
            Log.e("",""+t5);
            t.setText(t5);
        }
    else
        {
            t.setText("No Event");
        }       
            c.moveToNext();
        }
            c.close();

                }
                catch(SQLException e)
                {

                }
                // set selected date into textview
                tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                        .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));

                // set selected date into datepicker also
                dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

            }
        };


}
```

I am facing some problem and force close while storing and fetchind events in DB.please help me with any helpfull suggestions...here i am trying to compare date selected by datepicker with database stored date and displaying the event on that day.

Comment: you shouldn't be doing this in a callback. callbacks happen on the main thread and DB/network operations should always be done in the background. personally, i think it's best to create you tables in the onCreate method of you sqlite helper class.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from ICS you are crashing if you do any DB operation on main thread. As you are just trying to write a value in DB you could do like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        do_the_db_operations
    }
 }.start();
```

Comment: Why ? The only issue with this can be in terms of synchronisation. If the app is DB intensive and these kind of problems can arrise a queuing mechanism will be needed.

Comment: just spawning a thread doesn't allow any kind of easy return. you can call `runOnUiThread` at the end of your runnable, but it's easier (and IMHO better) to use an AsyncTask instead of a simple thread.

Comment: That's true if you need to return on main thread. In the case described by the OP it's not.

Comment: he's updating the ui based on a DB read. so yes, he is returning to the main thread.

Comment: can anyone please suggest me an easy way to solve this problem?i am very much in need of it.thanks

Comment: Can you post the log from logcat ? Maybe you have multiple problems there.

Comment: @azertiti : this is my log cat:                                     12-21 07:21:30.731: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 49K, 53% free 2549K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 82ms
12-21 07:21:44.621: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 79K, 51% free 2660K/5379K, external 2672K/2811K, paused 65ms
12-21 07:21:57.502: E/(374): 11
12-21 07:21:57.502: E/(374): 17
12-21 07:22:03.331: W/KeyCharacterMap(374): No keyboard for id 0
12-21 07:22:03.331: W/KeyCharacterMap(374): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Answer (score 0):

DB accesses can be run on the UI thread. An Activity can call finish() on itself. But any Android engineer who saw you doing this would shake his or her head sadly.

In other words, do DB access on the background.

What's missing from this whole discussion is the logCat for the force close. What's going wrong? We're only speculating here, and without a logCat, the speculation is purely
while (true) {
  int i = 0;
}